# Transcribe + Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, transcribe

I have a current project that uses Expresso Store and I need to make the site multilingual (including the products available in the store). I am debating on using Transcribe to handle the heavy lifting of making the site multi-lingual and the products on sale, but I'm thinking there may be a problem. If Transcribe basically creates a duplicate related entry for the translation will this also duplicate the products in Store? (i.e.; Inventory items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that Store and Transcribe do not play nice together. Things like modifier names, email templates, error messages would only be shown in the default language.

The only officially supported way of having a multilingual setup with Store would be to use MSM and have each site as a language.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Didn't think about the email templates or error messages (in this particular case product modifiers aren't going to be used).

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question remember to mark it as answered by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Does anyone know the best option for working around this -- e.g. disabling transcribe for the store pages? We have a site that is multilingual, but the store only needs to be in one language. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Hey Tom, following house rules it's best to ask a new 'question' as 'answers' are aimed at being exclusively for answering the original question. SE differs from regular forums in this respect. With regard to Transcribe however it's perfectly possible to integrate with Store and we have a number of customers who are using that combination successfully.